# Ruby Regex grabs unnecessary whitespace

Tags: ruby, regex

I am going to mark all of my `www` followed by `.` with a `foo`.

I currently have a ruby regex `[^https:\/\/]foo\.` to grab any foo that doesn't have a `https://` before it. This succesfully ignores the `https://` of any `https://foo` format and won't grab it.

However, it will grab the following from the following example

> ```
>    'the cat foo.this  =  _foo.'
>    'https     ://foo.this  =   none'
>    ' foo.this     =      _foo.'
>    'foo.this      =       foo.'
> ```

Why is it grabbing this whitespace(as I noted with the `_`) and how can I make it not do so?

Comment: Does your regex `[^https:\/\/]foo\.` contains typo?

Comment: `[^https:\/\/]` is a negated character class, not an assertion.

Answer (score 1):

`[^https:\/\/]` means "any single character that is not `h`, `t`, `p`, `s`, `:`, or `/`".  That is not at all what you want.

Comment: This seems to work for my scenario, but the title of the problem is about the necessary white space, so everything else works for now

Comment: No, it doesn't.  `[^https:\/\/]` matches a space.  That's the problem.  If it happens to also work as desired in some situations, that's pure coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you're going to mark all of 'www' followed by '.' with a 'foo'.

But your regex is doing nothing like that.

`/(?<!https:\/\/)www\.foo/` should do your job.

Comment: I used foo instead of www. because the question formating was complaining my regex is /(?<!https:\/\/)www\./

Answer (score 0):

The [^https://] part was wrong like you guys said, I got caught up and wanted to use it because it was the only thing that kind of worked for the last few hours. 
I ended up just selecting all of the strings with https://foo.com and foo.com and replaced them with https://foo.com

thanks for all the help guys